# For loop in Visual Studio Pro 2013

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am taking a course on visual C++ and according to the text, the following code should work (exact copy and paste of the text). Intellisense is saying otherwise, claiming there are 5 errors (informing me that cnt2: undeclared identifier, missing ";" before "{" and missing ";" before "}"). I have never attempted this before with any language (quite honestly didn't know it was a possibility), so any enlightening would be appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
// Program 2.: Program demonstrates the for-loop.

int main()
{   
    using namespace std;

    for (int cnt1 = 0, int cnt2 = 9; cnt1 < 10; ++cnt1, --cnt2)
    {
        cout << cnt1 << "---Hello, World!---" << cnt2 << endl;
    }
}
```

Exact text from my book:
This time there are two counter variables (separated by commas), which are initialized to 0 and 9. Moreover, one is incremented and the other is decremented. Consequently, as shown from the output, one counts forward and one counts backwards. Part 2-the condition-remains the same; that is, it still specifies that we loop ten times.

What am I doing wrong here? Does visual studio 2013 professional not allow this operation? The text said to use Visual C++ to program, I am just more comfortable with VS.

Comment: Your book tells you to put a `#include` inside the `main()` function?  Seriously, get another book!

Comment: Also, instead of int cnt2 = 9; make it cnt2 = 9;

Comment: See if there are any errata available online for the book. Most publishers put them up on their web sites.

Comment: The #include was in the correct place, I just initially missed it on the copy and pasted it in the wrong place. The int is included and seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be like this

```
// Program 2.: Program demonstrates the for-loop.

#include <iostream>

int main()
{   
    using namespace std;

    for (int cnt1 = 0, cnt2 = 9; cnt1 < 10; ++cnt1, --cnt2)
    {
        cout << cnt1 << "---Hello, World!---" << cnt2 << endl;
    }
}
```

errors in your version:

1) You cannot include header-files of standard-library in function-scope (and your include was not properly ended, you forgot '>' symbol).

2) When you declare variables in loop type should be pointed only before first.

Comment: Don't forget to return something, most likely 0.

Comment: @DanShield read C++ standard please, 0 will be returned by default.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that he forgot the closing `>` in the `#include`.